# unable to load html table through onclick

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I have a function which loads a html table with sql data query and a html page to display the table when i click the button but it is not showing the table, it just shows the url changing to match my search but does not display the table
Function code:

```
function Search()
{
    var search = new Object;
    search.restaurantName = document.getElementById("searchinput").value; //get input

var searchrestaurant = new XMLHttpRequest();
searchrestaurant.open("POST", Search_url, true);
searchrestaurant.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

searchrestaurant.onload = function() 
{

    search_array = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    result();


}

searchrestaurant.send(JSON.stringify(search));



}



function result()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("result"); 
        table.innerHTML = "";

    result = search_array.length

for (var count = 0; count < result; count++)
{
    // data from sql
    var restaurant_name = search_array[count].restaurant_name;
    var Description = search_array[count].Description;
    var location = search_array[count].location;
    var thumbnail = search_array[count].thumbnail;
    var price = search_array[count].price;
    var rating = search_array[count].avg_rating;


    //table to show all sql data
    var AllrestaurantTable = "<table class = fixed style=width:100% border=1px>" +

                                "<tr>"+
                                    "<td>" +"<a href = 'detailed_restaurant.html' target ='_blank'>"+"<img src ='" + thumbnail + "'style=width:100px;height:100px;></img>"+"</td>" +
                                    "<td>"+"<a href = 'detailed_restaurant.html' target ='_blank'>"+ restaurant_name  + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>"+ location + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>"+ Description + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>"+ price + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>"+ rating + "</td>"

                                "</tr>" +
                            "</table>";



    table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', AllrestaurantTable);


 }
   }
```

Html:

```
<body>
<form id = "SearchForm">
    <label>Search </label>
    <input type="text" id="searchinput" name="restaurantName">
    <input type="button" onclick="Search()" value="Submit">
</form>

<div class="container"></div>


    <div id="result" class="row"></div>

     </div>
```

I have already loaded the script into the html site but it is just take my input and does not display the table i created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenation operator is missing after `"<td>" + rating + "</td>"`.

Add the `+` operator. like `"<td>" + rating + "</td>"`  `+`.

```js
 function result() {
            var table = document.getElementById("result");
            table.innerHTML = "";
            result = 5
            for (var count = 0; count < result; count++) {
                // data from sql
                var restaurant_name = 1;
                var Description = 'ddf';
                var location = 'location';
                var thumbnail = 1;
                var price = 'Price';
                var rating = 'rating';

                //table to show all sql data
                var AllrestaurantTable = "<table class = fixed style=width:100% border=1px>" +
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + "<a href = 'detailed_restaurant.html' target ='_blank'>" + "<img src ='" + thumbnail + "'style=width:100px;height:100px;></img>" + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + "<a href = 'detailed_restaurant.html' target ='_blank'>" + restaurant_name + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + location + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + Description + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + price + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + rating + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>" +
                    "</table>";
               
                table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', AllrestaurantTable);

            }
        }
        result();
```

```html
 <div id="result" class="row"></div>
    </div>
```

You have to pass the search array in your result function.

```
function Search() {
    var search = new Object;
    search.restaurantName = document.getElementById("searchinput").value; //get input
    var searchrestaurant = new XMLHttpRequest();
    searchrestaurant.open("POST", Search_url, true);
    searchrestaurant.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    searchrestaurant.onload = function () {
        search_array = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        result(search_array);

    }
    searchrestaurant.send(JSON.stringify(search));

}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: The `+` is missing after rating `td` that's why it's not printing on screen, Try now

Comment: Thanks you for trying to help but the operator was not the issue, the table is still not showing up

Comment: Run the above code , I have only changed the variable values to some static values and it is working.

Comment: it works but when i try to put it into the webpage it still show up as empty even though i have data. Could it be document.getElementById("searchinput").value; issue by any chance?

Comment: could you check if you have data in `result` and  `search_array`

Comment: In result function before `for` loop add this lines. `console.log(search_array);` and open the dev tool and check console.

Comment: You have to pass the search array in your result function `result(search_array);` on Ajax response, and try.

Comment: i think it not even calling my function when i click the button, that why the console.log show up empty

Comment: could you add console.log in ajax response

Comment: yea it not even running Search() on my ajax, i tried entering a console log and it doesn't even show up on my console

Comment: to clarify ajax is working but searchrestaurant.onload isn't working

Comment: now it working i think as i changed the onload to the correct variable, thank you so much for helping me dude :)